# Resize NSWindow from bottom left corner only?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

I am writing an application that sits in the OS X menu bar and when you press its icon a little NSPanel opens up. I would like the user to be able to resize it, but only by dragging the bottom left corner. I want to prevent them from being able to drag the top edge down and "unstick" the window from the menu bar.

Answer (score 1):

Just override <strike>`touchesBegan`</strike> `mouseDown:` and pass on the drag only if it is in the designated corner, discarding other touches.

See [Cocoa Event Handling Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/HandlingMouseEvents/HandlingMouseEvents.html)

Comment: Sorry - overlooked that... Still, conceptionally this is what I would do. Look at the section on handling mouse events in the [Cocoa Event Handling Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/HandlingMouseEvents/HandlingMouseEvents.html)

Comment: How would you prevent the *resize pointer* from showing up when the mouse is over the undesired corner/edge though?

Comment: Maybe you could modify your panel's style mask and set the `NSResizableWindowMask` to false. You would have to handle the touch in the lower right yourself. Also have a look at the NSWindow Notifications to maybe catch events.